# Getting an absolute local path in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I looked around, and the latest reference I saw was from 2008 stating that the standard `FileReference` browser does not support retrieving the user's file's absolute local path unless it's an AIR app, and indeed there's nothing in the docs suggesting otherwise. The reasoning behind this is apparently some misguided security concern... I get it's not a great idea to let any Flash app know your directory structure, but if the user actually grants your app a file, I think it doesn't invalidate the security model to know just that file's absolute path.

I'm wondering if the state of things has changed at all with Flex 4 and there's a method of getting the local filename of anything. I need it because I'm making an application that when distributed runs locally in 99% of cases, so doing a full file upload just to save it somewhere else on the local machine seems silly. (Plus the standard file uploading method doesn't support SOAP, which is what I'm using for all my other services...) I can always just have the user type in their local path name, but that seems really stupid.

Comment: Now I'm curious why someone would downvote me. This is legitimately a bad security decision unless one really believes all intranet applications should be exported to AIR. I'll concede that an argument for, say, picture previewing doesn't hold since you can get the data without the path, unless you also want to represent a tree of images similar to the user's file system.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, but since you have 1 rep, they're the ones that lost reputation. Maaaan.. a lot of trigger-happy people online today :)

Comment: if people are to !"smart" to understand the problem they just vote down... Shame on them!

Answer (score 3):

Due to security reasons, in Flash (not AIR) you are not allowed to see the full path of a fileReference File.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve - it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do.

> "doing a full file upload just to save it somewhere else on the local machine seems silly"

Since flash player 10 you can save directly to the local filesystem without going through a remote server. You just have to invoke the `FileReference.download()` function in response to a user guesture like a mouse click or key press (e.g. pressing a save button).

FileReference documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29

Otherwise, no, you are not able to get the full path to a file as it can be a security risk - even if they do select the file themselves.

For example if I select a file on the desktop of a Windows machine I don't really want some random web application knowing my username:

"C:\Documents and Settings\ **[user name]** \Desktop\myAwesomeFile.txt"

and from that you can take a guess at the version of windows I'm running.

If you need greater interaction with a user's desktop then you should use AIR - that is it's reason for existing.

Comment: How can I load a video file that the user selects?  Do any Flash APIs involving the loading of video files accept a "FileReference" as a source parameter?  Oh, no, they don't, so we need the full path to do anything useful with local files, unless you can deal directly with the loaded bytes.

Comment: "How can I load a video file that the user selects?" You deploy an AIR -based application that can do this; it is not the job of a web-based Flash Application. It's the same kind of security sandboxing that web-based JavaScript content has (and for the same reasons). It's very difficult to selectively secure and trust content from the internet (Java applets are a prime example of this) which is why AIR has a different deployment and security model.

Comment: Actually, I can load a video directly from the bytes obtained with FileReference via NetStream.appendBytes method.  The catch is that it only supports FLV headers, so I'm out of luck since all my files are the newer F4V format.  I shouldn't need a separate runtime (AIR) to load a local file.  Flash supports it, since SWFs can access either local files or the network.  The problem is that the ActionScript APIs require full paths, and fail to accept a FileReference.  Obviously the lack of support for F4V is a failure as well.  The video class could use a loadBytes or load(FileReference) method.